# ERROR: dependency [rosjava] cannot be found

Tags: eclipse, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I fallowed this lecture that it make C++ file in eclipse.

So, he typed this command `roscreate-pkg test roscpp`.

But I try to make java project, so I use rosjava

I found the tutorial of rosjava and it mentioned that I should type this command `roscreate-pkg test rosjava`.

however, there is a error

```
ERROR: dependency [rosjava] cannot be found
```

How can I figure out it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228770/error:-dependency-%5Brosjava%5D-cannot-be-found/) by [kmyang85@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/26239/kmyang85@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means you haven't installed `rosjava`.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-<YOURDISTRO>-rosjava` (replace `<YOURDISTROY` with `indigo`, `jade`, or whatever you are using).

Also, you should consider switching to `catkin` rather then using `rosbuild`...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmyang85@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/26239/kmyang85@gmail.com/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thank you for your answer.

however, I already installed it with  this command  sudo apt-get install ros--rosjava